# Maintaining Line Breaks Through Facebook API Usage

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

When using the api and javascript to display the description of an event, how can i preserve the line breaks?

```
query.wait(function(rows) {

document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML =
    new Date(rows[0].start_time * 1000) +  "<br />" +
    rows[0].start_time +  "<br />" +
    rows[0].end_time +  "<br />" +
    rows[0].location +  ", " +
    rows[0].venue['street'] +
    rows[0].venue['city'] + ", " +
    rows[0].venue['state'] +  "<br />" +
    rows[0].description;


;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/pre) to preserve white space characters, such as `\t` and `\n`.